# EXTJS4-how to implement search box

Tags: extjs, extjs4

how to have a search box(or search field) in a EXTJS page.

I tried the following, but nothing is being displayed in the page:
1. added SearchField.js in WebContent/ext/ux folder.
2. coded the following:

```
    Ext.Loader.setConfig({
            enabled: true,
            paths: {
                'Ext.ux': 'ext/ux'
            }
        });
        Ext.require([
                     'Ext.ux.form.SearchField'
                 ]);
    Ext.onReady(function () {
    var win=Ext.create('widget.window',{
            title: 'Super User Access Management',
            height: 480,
            width: 640,
    border:false,
              items       : [ 
{
          xtype      : 'combobox',
          fieldLabel : 'Module',

          value: 'Super Admin' ,
          store: ['Super Admin', 'Partner Contact Management', 'Partner Trainning Management'],
          listeners: {
              select: function(){
               alert('Hello module!');
              }
            }        
            },
            {
              xtype      : 'combobox',

              value: 'Infogain' ,
              store: ['Infogain', 'IBM', 'Mocrosoft'],
              listeners: {
                    select: function(){
                     alert('Hello partner!');
                    }
                  }        
                },
     {
                        xtype: 'searchfield',
                        height: 30,
                        id: 'searchField',
                        styleHtmlContent: true,
                        width: 320,
                        fieldLabel: '',
                    },
{ 
                  xtype: 'gridpanel',
                  border: false,
                  title:'Empty grid',
                  columns: [{header: 'World'}], 
                  store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}) 
                  }
       ]
        });
        win.show();
    });
```

please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to put the ux inside the ext/ux/form folder

Comment: Suppose, I have two drop boxes, one search box and a grid. I want to show drpbx1 at top, then below in one line left side drpbx2 and right side search box and below that the grid. Can you suggest, what layout I should use and what special config  needed. Edited the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer on the comment under the question:

I use a [`Ext.toolbar.Toolbar`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar) for that purpose.

[image: Like This]

You can place the toolbar in a container with the `dockedItems` config.

Comment: No, I could do it successfully. Thanks!

Comment: You really should Accept @A1rPun's answer to give him credit for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
tbar: [
    'Search : ', ' ',
    new Ext.ux.form.SearchField({
     store: store,
         width:320
             })
    ]
```

add the code in you form..specify the `store` ..